# Factorial - Array - C++

Tags: c++, arrays, integer, factorial

The problem is to compute factorial of a number. I've debugged my code, and it works fine for any input and produces **correct** output for all the given test cases. But still, I'm getting Wrong Answer on SPOJ.

**Problem:**

An integer t, 1<=t<=100, denoting the number of testcases, followed by t lines, each containing a single integer n, 1<=n<=100.

Any insight would be helpful. Am I missing some critical test cases?

**My Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

long T;
cin>>T;
while(T--)
{
    long long N;

    long long index, count;
    cin>>N;
    long long a[300];
    long long i=1;
    a[0]=1; count=1;
    while(i<=N)
    {

        long long z=0;
        long long k; long long x;
        long long j=i;
        long long temp=0; long long current=0;
        for(k=0; k<count;k++)
        {
            x=(a[k]*j)+temp;
            a[k]=x%10;
            temp=x/10;
        }
        if(temp>0)
            while(temp>0)
            {
                a[k]=temp;
                temp=temp/10;
                k++;
                count++;
            }


        i++;
    }


    for(long long g=count-1; g>=0; g--)
        cout<<a[g];
        cout<<"\n";

}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just to make sure: What is your result for 100! ?

Comment: Your code fails for 15!. It prints `11307674368000` instead of `1307674368000`

Comment: Actually I just checked the number of trailing zeros for 100! and assumed it to be correct without checking the actual values. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

> ```
> a[k]=temp;
> ```

should be:

```
a[k]=temp % 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out

```
#include <iostream>

long double factorial(int n)
{
    long double r = 1;

    while(n > 1){
        r *= n;
        --n;
    }

    return r;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << factorial(100) << std::endl;

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: double loses precision and gives incorrect answers for SPOJ, as it's conversion to string is different. In fact your, factorial(100) != 100!