# What is wrong with this recursive factorial implementation?

Tags: c++, recursion

I compiled and run in my computer, and it executes correctly. I tried IDEONE, and I got a successful answer.

But when I submit it in SPOJ, I'm getting a wrong answer. Is something wrong in this implementation?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int factorial(int n) {
    if (n <= 1)
        return 1;

    return n * factorial(n - 1);
}

int main() {
    int t;
    int n;

    cout << "";
    cin >> t;

    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        cout << "";
        cin >> n;

        printf("%d\n", factorial(n));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which question? If it's [this](http://www.spoj.com/problems/FCTRL/) one then you haven't read the requirements correctly.

Comment: ...or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23874020/factorial-array-c), where `n` can be any value from 1..100, and I can tell you right now, 100! won't stand a chance of fitting in a system `int`.

Comment: I'm doing this : http://www.spoj.com/problems/FCTRL2/

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the above code is due to the finite space we can use to store the value of an `int`. On a 32-bit machine, `int`'s have 32 bits (value 0 or 1), which means that the maximum value an `unsigned int` can have is (2^31 - 1) and the maximum value an `int` can have is (2^30 - 1) (since it needs one bit to denote whether it is positive or negative, while the `unsigned int` is always positive and can devote that bit to just regular value).

Now, that aside, you should look into ways of storing the value of a very large number in a different data structure! Maybe an array would be a good choice...

Just to brainstorm, imagine creating an `int bigInteger[100]` (that should be large enough to hold 100!). To multiply two of your numbers, you could then implement a `bitMultiplication(int bitNum[], int num)` function that would take in your array by reference and perform bitwise multiplication (see the following post for details: [Multiplying using Bitwise Operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20340961/multiplying-using-bitwise-operators)).

Use that `bitMulitiplication(int bitNum[], int num)` instead of the regular multiplication in your recursive factorial function, and you should have a function that works on large n!